# Installing Imagick on IIS?

Tags: php, iis, imagemagick, imagick, ini

I am trying to install Imagick on IIS.  This is the first time I've tried installing an extension for PHP, so I'd appreciate if someone could help me out.

I downloaded the recommended binary program for ImageMagick for Windows and installed it.  Then, I downloaded v3.1.2 of Imagick from http://pecl.php.net/package/imagick.

I opened the archive, and found a bunch of `C`, `H`, and other files.  I have no idea what to do now.  o.O  Am I supposed to do something with those files?

[image]

Then there was an `examples` folder with PHP files.  Finally, something familiar!  :)

I also downloaded the archive from the website labeled `DLL`.  There's a bunch of files in there as well.

Anyway, I'd really appreciate if someone could help me out here.  I am using PHP v5.3, and the `phpinfo()` says the system is `Windows Server 2008 R2 Web Server Edition...`...hope that helps...

I am not experienced with installing PHP extensions, and the documentation isn't really that good... :/

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You downloaded the ImageMagick source code which would need to be compiled into binaries that get installed on your system to use.  If you don’t want to do that—and I am guessing by your question, you don’t—then I recommend installing it from the [precompiled binaries located here](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php).

> ImageMagick runs on Windows 8 (x86 & x64), Windows 7 (x86 & x64),
> Windows XP (x86) with Service Pack 3, Windows Vista (x86 & x64) with
> Service Pack 2, Windows Server 2003 (x86 & x64) with Service Pack 2
> (verify MSXML6 is present), Windows Server 2003 R2 (x86 & x64),
> Windows Server 2008 (x86 & x64) with Service Pack 2, and Windows
> Server 2008 R2 (x64).
>
> The amount of memory can be an important factor, especially if you
> intend to work on large images. A minimum of 512 MB of RAM is
> recommended, but the more RAM the better. Although ImageMagick runs
> well on a single core computer, it automagically runs in parallel on
> multi-core systems reducing run times considerably.
>
> The Windows version of ImageMagick is self-installing. Simply click on
> the appropriate version below and it will launch itself and ask you a
> few installation questions. Versions with Q8 in the name are 8
> bits-per-pixel component (e.g. 8-bit red, 8-bit green, etc.), whereas,
> Q16 in the filename are 16 bits-per-pixel component. A Q16 version
> permits you to read or write 16-bit images without losing precision
> but requires twice as much resources as the Q8 version. Versions with
> dll in the filename include ImageMagick libraries as dynamic link
> libraries. Unless you have specific requirements, we recommend this
> version of ImageMagick for 32-bit Windows.

Comment: I had already installed that, but I thought the ImageMagick and Imagick were two different downloads.  I downloaded Imagick, and that's what had all those files.  ImageMagick appears to have installed fine, but what do I need to do in order to install Imagick and get it to work with PHP?  Thanks!!